# start service or job when a notification received (without clicking it)

Tags: android, firebase

Is there any way for a notification to start a service or a job or background task ?? 
i am using FCM and on *onMessageReceive* method i am able to do what ever i want **if the app is in the foreground** .
i am looking for a way for 3 days and this is my second question on Stack , i will thank anyone who can help me beyond imagination . 
**JUST TO BE CLEAR** i want to download data from firebase DB when i get notification no matter what is the status of the app.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked. Also have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i think you are a little bit over serious , my question is very simple ! with the help of FCM i am able to receive notification and start a background job but only if the app is in the **foreground** . now my simple question is , is there any way to to do it in **background**? @RosárioPereiraFernandes
in another words is there a way for notification to trigger a job while app is in the background ?